# Formatting URLs with PHP / Apache Server

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I've tried searching and reformatting other's code but I seem to be getting nowhere.

I want to format my URLs to be something like:

```
www.site.com/search/2/atoz/under10
```

Instead of:

```
www.site.com/search.php?page=2&order=name&price=under10
```

I've searched and read about ModRewrite but am having trouble with it.

- Do I just stick this code in the .htacces file?
- Do I need to change how I generate my links in my actual site code to match the format I want to be using?
- What if one of the query string parameters is missing? (eg.
  www.site.com/search.php? page=2&price=under10 with no "order" in the
  Query String)
- How do I handle other pages on the site? (eg. browse.php?order=newest&color=green)

Any advice or resources I should be looking at are much appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't use resources in place of search parameters. Your URL is perfectly fine the way it is now. See [how to process php REST url resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663868/how-to-process-php-rest-url-resources).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you only need to use .htaccess file.

Yes, you need to write link in your code that match your new format (ie: .com/site/articles/1)

ModRewrite can handle that if you write something good (not only (.*))

More line and line in your .htaccess